# CSS3 selector issue

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating my contact page for my portfolio website and I'm having some problems with selectors. I have a good knowledge base of both HTML and CSS. And I'm now making the transition to HTML5/CSS3.

I'm having a problem doing any modifications to the h2 on the page. It seems when I try and target the h2 in CSS it doesn't make any changes. Am I missing something that needs to be added in because it's using HTML5 elements? Or am I just not using the correct DOM to the element to make changes? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!-- HTML5 -->
<section>
    <h2 class="pages">Contact</h2>
<article>
</article>
</section>

<!-- CSS3 -->
section h2 .pages
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJgLr/)

---

Your selector is slightly wrong, use this instead:

```
section h2.pages {
  color:red;
}
```

**Edit:**

Files in relation to comments:

http://www.speedyshare.com/2eSXY/contact.php

http://www.speedyshare.com/Z5exc/screen.css.css

Comment: Please avoid going into extended discussions in comments in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock Apologies, I've flagged these comments for removal, if you're still online, d'ya reckon you could remove them? thanks!

Comment: No problem - I've done that now, but I'll leave my notice up for the asker's reference.